# Communicate between two instances of state component created via map in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a component that uses data in the form

```
const pkgData = {
    name: 'XYX',
    content: 'Dummy text',
    currency: 'INR',
    variants: [
    {
        name: 'Breakfast',
        content: 'ttdtd',
        subvariants: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Adults',
                originalPrice: '1',
                fixedPrice: '2',
            }, {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Kiddies',
                originalPrice: '45',
                fixedPrice: '45',
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        name: 'Lunch',
        content: 'ttdtd',
        subvariants: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Adults',
                originalPrice: '1',
                fixedPrice: '2',
            }, {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Kiddies',
                originalPrice: '45',
                fixedPrice: '45',
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Dinner',
        content: 'ttdtd',
        subvariants: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Adults',
                originalPrice: '1',
                fixedPrice: '2',
            }, {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Kiddies',
                originalPrice: '45',
                fixedPrice: '45',
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

In my return function I am using : `pkgData.variants.map((e,index) => <ComponentB variant={e} key={index}  currency='INR' />)`

In my component B , I am managing a state, that increments the quantity of sub variant.

So how will that state be communicating with each other?
Will that state be separate instance for each occurence?

Comment: You have to change the parent component's state. Pass an event to `ComponentB` that does this and call it on `ComponentB` when you want to add new sub variants.

Comment: let suppose component B has a button  when clicked it will update the state relative to component A. is this  what you trying to achieve ?

Comment: for each variant element in an array , a separate SELECT button is getting created. This button is used to display details of each array element like subvariants. What I am trying to achieve is that on clicking Select button of one element only that one should show it's details. THe details of other should be shown when their button is clicked. At a time the details of single item can be shown.